# Multiple left joins and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, erd

I am building a stock control system and have stumbled on this problem, which I cannot solve despite various hours spent googling and trying different options.

Essentially each product can be stored in multiple locations, from which order items are assigned amounts to come from each location via the order item location table (allowing picks to continue if a location empties etc). Each order has a timestamped entry into order_process for recording when it reached certain stages (received, picked, shipped etc) and the assigning of order item locations happens when an order is placed.

I need to query the database for each "product variant" selected (by using the foreign key in the product locations table) and display each location along with any stock which has been ordered and not dispatched from the order item locations table (orders with the below the MAX(order_process_process_id) of 4).

The MySQL I have so far takes a long time to execute (7.8 seconds compared to instantaneous when I started)and I need the totals of the order_item_location_quantity and order_item_location_removed for each item, which I can't currently do due to the left join.

I'm stuck. Any pointers?

Below is a section of my EERD:

[image: EERD]

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT
    product_location_id,
    product_location_variant_id,
    product_location_ref,
    product_location_stock,
    product_location_primary,
    product_location_deleted,
    order_item_location_order_item_id as oi_id,
    order_item_location_quantity as oi_location_quantity,
    order_item_location_removed as oi_location_removed
FROM
    (tbl_product_locations)
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        order_item_location_order_item_id,
        order_item_location_location_id,
        order_item_location_quantity,
        order_item_location_removed
    FROM
        tbl_order_items AS oitem
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_order_item_locations ON order_item_id = order_item_location_order_item_id
    JOIN
        tbl_order_progress ON order_progress_order_id = order_item_order_id
    GROUP BY
        order_item_id
    HAVING
        MAX(order_progress_progress_id) < 4
) oi ON product_location_id = oi.order_item_location_location_id
WHERE
    `product_location_variant_id` =  '13081'
AND
    `product_location_deleted` =  0
GROUP BY
    product_location_id
ORDER BY
    product_location_ref ASC
```

**EDIT**

Output:

[image]

EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

[image]

Comment: have you thought about using product_location_variant_id IN (id1,id2,id3,...)

Comment: also if you add what your current query is outputting and what your desired output is I could help you better

Comment: also, please post the `explain` output for your query

Comment: Your `tbl_orders` requires some serious normalization. You potentially have repeating data in columns like `order_country` etc

Comment: BTW, price should be DECIMAL. And customers should almost certainly be held in a seprate table from orders. I really wouldn't bother posting the EXPLAIN for this. Sort out your design first (it's not that bad, but needs a little work)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @JeremyC. This is queried inside a PHP foreach loop so it doesn't need the  product_location_variant_id IN (id1,id2,id3,...). Please find my output and explain there too. I can't normalise the country field because it comes in from a plain text box from their e-commerce system, but I agree with the rest of the customers normalisation.

Comment: @ConsiderMe - Potentially you actually want to store it off - it depends on what kind of auditing/logging you need to do.  Hopefully there is a separate table for the usual customer info, but often for orders you want to store slightly denormalized data for traceability purposes.  @Phil - you will want to change to using `DECIMAL` for money.  And having `GROUP BY` in the outer query is suspicious - you should be elimination duplicates before that point (especially as the other columns will have non-deterministic values).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse we don't store the customer data in this system, this is a back end warehousing system and that is more normalised in the front end system. I've removed the GROUP BY and it's shaved 0.1 seconds off, but I think it's the left join to the subquery thats causing the biggest drop in speed.

Comment: LEFT JOINs are slower than INNER JOINs in a lot of circumstances.  Also, your first LEFT JOIN joins with an in line view expressed as a subquery.  This slows things down as well.  Explain to us why INNER JOINs would give the wrong results and why the inline view can't be combined into a single query.

Comment: How much data do you have?  Is it millions of rows?  Hundreds of millions?